# NDEigensystem returns reversed list of eigenfuctions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I'm considering the two coupled linear differential operators

```
eq = {(-2 I bf[r] - (2 + r^2) br[r] + 
    r (Derivative[1][br][r] + r Derivative[2][br][r]))/(
   50 r^2), -(((2 + r^2) bf[r] + (-2 I + 100 E^-r^2 r^4) br[r] - 
     r (Derivative[1][bf][r] + r Derivative[2][bf][r]))/(
    50 r^2))};
```

and solving eigenvalue problem

```
R0 = 1/2; R1 = 2;
{evals, efuns} = 
 NDEigensystem[{eq[[1]] + NeumannValue[0, r == R0], 
   eq[[2]] + NeumannValue[0, r == R0], 
   DirichletCondition[br[r] == 0, r == R1], 
   DirichletCondition[bf[r] == 0, r == R1]}, {br, bf}, {r, R0, R1}, 
  20];
```

How I want to check result for the first value. The residual seems too large

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Abs[(eq - evals[[1]] {br[r], bf[r]}) /. {br -> efuns[[1, 1]], 
     bf -> efuns[[1, 2]]}]], {r, R0, R1}]
```

[image]

Surprisingly, the result is much better if I take the reverse sequence `br -> efuns[[1, 2]], bf -> efuns[[1, 1]]`. It gives

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Abs[(eq - evals[[1]] {br[r], bf[r]}) /. {br -> efuns[[1, 2]], 
     bf -> efuns[[1, 1]]}]], {r, R0, R1}]
```

[image]

I don't understend why is it so. Have you any idea?

Comment: I am not at a computer right now, but could the [ordering of dependet variables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#898113620) be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment above, this is because of an issue described in the documentation: [Ordering of dependent variables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#898113620). The simplest way to deal with this is to specify the "DependentVariables" option:

```
R0 = 1/2; R1 = 2;
{evals, efuns} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eq[[1]] + NeumannValue[0, r == R0], 
    eq[[2]] + NeumannValue[0, r == R0], 
    DirichletCondition[br[r] == 0, r == R1], 
    DirichletCondition[bf[r] == 0, r == R1]}, {br, bf}, {r, R0, R1}, 
   20, "DependentVariables" -> {br, bf}];
```

Which then gives:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Abs[(eq - evals[[1]] {br[r], bf[r]}) /. {br -> efuns[[1, 1]], 
     bf -> efuns[[1, 2]]}]], {r, R0, R1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]